# Use external google-services.json file in library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, google-signin, google-authentication

I'm sharing a single login module across my apps, with a  `LoginActivity` that handles both Facebook and Google auth (logic + UI).
Now, with Facebook it's easy to specify a different ID for each app, overriding the library's `facebook_app_id` string in the app module.

I didn't find a way to do the same with Google Sign-In because it requires a `google-services.json` file. In fact, the build fails if I include the file in the app modules and not in the login library.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':core:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
>   
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

The error is self-explanatory, I **need** `google-services.json` in the login module. The point is that the other apps have their own `google-services.json` too.

Is there a way I can add a dummy `google-services.json` in the Login module and then override it in each app with the real one?

Comment: Did you try actually providing the missing google-services.json to see what happens next?

Comment: Yeah, it works if I provide the file. But I want to add a different google-services.json for each module, because each module has a different package name and login config.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't have a `google-services.json` file in a library.
You have to **add the dependencies** needed, and it is enough to compile to library.

Instead in the projects which will use the library, you have to add the plugin and the `google-services.json` file.

To do it in your library, in the `build.gradle` you **have to remove** the line

```
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thanks, so I guess there's no way to share Google login GUI and logic between my apps, right? That's bad, with Facebook I just override the id string.

Comment: @PaoloRotolo You can do it. Read better the answer. To build the google login just add the dependencies. It is enough to compile. You dont' need the json file to do it. Each apps will have own google-services.json and can reuse the login build in the common module.

Comment: I have removed the apply plugin line from the build.gradle, but building the library still gives me the warning.

```
google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0 will be used.
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
```

Is this unavoidable?

Comment: To add onto this for any future visitors, I was able to access the values I needed in the library by getting the `FirebaseOptions` with a context from the main application passed into the library. This was after just having the google-services.json and the services dependency in the main app module.