# Should I duplicate google-services.json for different modules of the same project?

Tags: android, gradle

I am working with a multi-module project : 
`/app` 
`/firebase`

In the `/app` module, i have my `google-services.json` auto-generated by Android Studio.

In the `/firebase` module, i would like to use the firebase remote-config and i have this error message :

```
google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
 Searched Location: 
D:\...\firebase\src\nullnull\google-services.json
D:\...\firebase\src\debug\google-services.json
D:\...\firebase\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
D:\...\firebase\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
D:\...\firebase\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
D:\...\firebase\google-services.json
```

Should i copy/paste my google-services.json from `/app` ?

Comment: i found a solutoin : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41920680/7528285